Lemma of Partial Differential Equations Theory

Let $N \in \Bbb{N}, \Omega \subseteq \Bbb{R}^N$ an open bounded set with regular boundary and $u \in \mathcal{C}^\infty(\overline{\Omega} ; \Bbb{R})$ a map satisfying:

$\Delta(\Delta u)=0$ at $\Omega$
$u=0$ at $\partial \Omega$
$\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} = 0$ at $\partial \Omega$ 
Then $u = 0$ at all $\overline{\Omega}$


I have seen this lemma suggested as a exercise to the reader on my book and I am trying to prove it.
My idea was to apply Green's First Formula: $$\int_\Omega \Delta u \cdot v \, dV = \int_{\partial \Omega} \frac{\partial u}{\partial n} \cdot v \, dS - \int_\Omega \langle \nabla u , \nabla v \rangle dV$$
but I am not sure the way to do it since I see two ways. The first consists on use the following ideas:

If a map $u$ satisfies that $u^2$ is armonic, then $u$ is constant.
The product of armonic maps $u,v$ is armonic iff $\langle \nabla u , \nabla v \rangle = 0$

Sustituying $v = u$ we have by the 3th hypothesis that: $$\int_\Omega \Delta u \cdot u \, dV = \int_{\partial \Omega} \frac{\partial u}{\partial n} \cdot u \, dS - \int_\Omega \langle \nabla u , \nabla u \rangle dV = - \int_\Omega \langle \nabla u , \nabla u \rangle dV $$
If $\Delta u \cdot u = 0$, we would have finished by using the previous mentioned ideas, but I do not see how to finish that step.
The other way consists on taking $v = \Delta u$ and note that $$\int_\Omega \Delta u \cdot \Delta u \, dV = \int_{\partial \Omega} \frac{\partial u}{\partial n} \cdot \Delta u \, dS - \int_\Omega \langle \nabla u , \nabla (\Delta u) \rangle dV = - \int_\Omega \langle \nabla u , \nabla (\Delta u) \rangle dV$$
Here I thought that maybe $\Delta (\Delta u)$ should be related to $\Delta u \cdot \Delta u $ and we can apply the 1st hypothesis, but I am not reaching it. Therefore, any idea or advice would be very appreciated.

Your second approach is in the right direction, you just have to apply integration by parts again. This will give you
$$ \int_{\Omega} \Delta u \cdot \Delta u \,dV = -\int_{\Omega} \langle \nabla u,\nabla (\Delta u)\rangle \,dV=\int_{\Omega}u \Delta(\Delta u)\,dV - \int_{\partial \Omega}u\frac{\partial}{\partial n}(\Delta u)\,dS=0.$$
We conclude from this that $\Delta u =0$, which implies $u$ is zero. To see this last claim, we compute
$$\int_{\Omega}\langle \nabla u, \nabla u\rangle \,dV=-\int_{\Omega}u\Delta u \,dV +\int_{\partial \Omega} u \frac{\partial u}{\partial n}\,dS=0,$$
which shows $\nabla u=0$. Hence, $u$ is constant and since it is zero at the boundary, $u$ must be zero.

Thanks for your help!
